# Shell script to monitor postgresql database status and alerts

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I need postgresql shell script to alert me if database is goes down.

Comment: ```while true; do psql -c "select 1"; if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then echo 'alert'; fi; sleep 1; done;```

Comment: Could u please tell me logic of this shell script.

Comment: it tries to connect to db once in a sec and if fails, echoes 'alert'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pg_isready` is a utility for checking the connection status of a PostgreSQL database server. The `exit` status specifies the result of the connection check.

Example:

```
while true; do
    if ! /usr/bin/pg_isready &>/dev/null; then 
        echo 'alert';
    fi;
    sleep 3;
done;
```

This will check the status of postgresql database every 3 seconds and echos "alert" if it is down.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pg-isready.html